# How to add custom JDBC dialects in PySpark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark, py4j

I have a custom JDBC Dialect in Scala, which works flawlessly through `registerDialect` method in Scala Spark API. I was hoping to use the same class in PySpark by accessing it through

```
sc._jvm.org.apache.spark.sql.jdbc.JdbcDialects.registerDialect(sc._jvm.com.me.MyJDBCDialect)
```

But I receive this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1124, in __call__
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1094, in _build_args
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 289, in get_command_part
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1363, in __getattr__
 py4j.protocol.Py4JError: com.me.MyJDBCDialect._get_object_id does not exist in the JVM
```

I'm totally unfamiliar with Py4J but it sounds like `_get_object_id` error is raised since `sc._jvm.com.me.MyJDBCDialect` is a Python object and I try to pass it to `sc._jvm.org.apache.spark.sql.jdbc.JdbcDialects.registerDialect`, which is a Java(?) construct. How do I get around this problem?

Comment: Sounds like your class path is messed up? Please include the code you use to distribute jars and set path.

Comment: `from py4j.java_gateway import java_import 
java_import(sc._jvm, "com.me.MyJDBCDialect")`
Would it be something like the above?

Comment: I also start PySpark by `pyspark --master yarn --deploy-mode client --jars MyJDBCDialect.jar`

Comment: Try adding `--conf spark.driver.extraClassPath=path/to/jar`

Comment: I could be mistaken, but `>>> dir(sc._jvm.com.me.MyJDBCDialect)
[u'beforeFetch', u'canHandle', u'getCatalystType', u'getJDBCType', u'getSchemaQuery', u'getTableExistsQuery', u'isCascadingTruncateTable', u'quoteIdentifier']` seems to reference all the correct attributes so classpath should be correct. I need to figure out how to pass JVM objects to one another withint Py4J.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

Make sure that your dialect is declared as `class`, not `object`

```
from py4j.java_gateway import java_import

gw = spark.sparkContext._gateway
java_import(gw.jvm, "com.me.MyJDBCDialect")
gw.jvm.org.apache.spark.sql.jdbc.JdbcDialects.registerDialect(
  gw.jvm.com.me.MyJDBCDialect())
```

Note the `()` - it will call class constructor for your dialect

Comment: Hey thanks for looking into this. When I run your code, I'm running into this error message: `py4j.Py4JException: Constructor com.me.MyJDBCDialect([]) does not exist`. Did you end up writing a constructor in your Java/Scala code?

Comment: **Make sure that your dialect is declared as class, not object** This should be bold, the Dialect should be a Scala class not an object.

Comment: anyone knows how to make the custom jdbc dialect to be importable in python? Should it be compiled to jar file and attach to spark session? I am not familiar with Scala. Anyone can provide a suggestion?

Comment: did anybody able to resolve this issue? if so please provide